# have trouble using template function on visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm reading the template section on C++Primer recently, and i want to try it on my VS2013.
I write a template find as following.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename iteratorT, typename valT>
iteratorT find(const iteratorT &up, const iteratorT &end, const valT &val)
{
    auto iter = up;
    while (iter != end && *iter != val)
        ++iter;
    return ++iter;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    auto i = find(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 7);
}
```

but visual studio tell me

```
    1   IntelliSense: more than one instance of function template "find" matches the argument list:
        function template "_InIt std::find(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, const _Ty &_Val)"
        function template "iteratorT find(const iteratorT &up, const iteratorT &end, const valT &val)"
        argument types are: (std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>, std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>, int)   d:\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source.cpp  16  11  ConsoleApplication1
```

I'm confused, I didn't use "using namespace std", can anyone tell me why will the std version of "find" come here ?

I'll be grateful for your help :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `vector` header file `algorithm` is included.
Due `ADL` find in namespace `std` will be used since `vector::const_iterator` is in `std` namespace. Same will be with `gcc` and `clang`, if `algorithm` header file is included manually.

Comment: I try it on gcc, it turns out exactly as you say, thanks a lot :D, I thought it was a bug...